# How add vertical slider that works with mobile touch screens?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, slider

I had a jquery UI vertical slider but it didn't work properly on mobile. There was a couple of plugins that claimed to enable jquery UI on phones but none seemed to work properly.

So I decided to recreate it with jquery mobile - but now I can't get it to work vertically. The only help I could find was a forum where someone said they "easily" hacked the code to make it work without showing how. I can't seem to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.elmundio.net/projects/verticalSlider/

I have made a demo that should do what you want.

I have simply overridden the default jquery slider with a modified version, and added a bit of extra CSS